# Disable dummy highcharts graph with CSS overlay and message "No data to show". AngularJS, no jQuery

Tags: css, angularjs, overlay

I've got some nice graphs, pie charts and bar charts. When there is no real data, I use dummy data fro show-off.

I'd like to simply keep the dummy charts the background, 'graying it out' and showing the message "No data to show". I don't want to mislead with dummy data presenting itself as the truth.

No, this is not the same as the newly released "no data for show" feature from Highcharts, it shows nothing, I want the teaser.

I've tried a lot, but my CSS skills aren't good enough right now, he admitted, embarrassed.

- two charts
- communicate "No data to show" in some overlay
- keeping the charts behind there as cool teasers

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You might use ng-if to accomplish this. Check the docs, the example at the bottom demos what you're looking for.

Copied from [Official ngIf Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /><br/>
    Show when checked:
    <span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
      I'm removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
.animate-if {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```